# How to keep my program alive for as long a daemon thread is running?

Tags: java, daemon

I have a requirement, that I want to start a poller once which will run foreever until the machine is restarted or the process is being killed. Now, I tried to start the poller from a main method using a shell script, but the problem is that as soon as the main method completed its execution, the poller also stoped working, as i am not using any servers to achieve so.

I heard something about `daemon threads`, but I am wondering how to create a daemon thread, which will run forever, and help my poller to run also.

UPDATE:

```
public class SomeThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        UnitPoller unitPoller = new UnitPoller();
        unitPoller.doPolling();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeThread someThread = new SomeThread();
        someThread.setDaemon(true);
        someThread.start();
    }
}
```

Above is my updated class, now whenever I execute this thread from the main method, it creates a thread but as soon as the execution of main method completes, my poller stops working, as the JVM shuts down.

With this problem, what should i do.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just create a thread and call `th.setDaemon(true)` before calling `th.start()`.

Edit:

The above answers the question "how to create a daemon thread", but (as the scope of the question has changed), a proper answer would be: *don't create a daemon thread* if you want your thread to keep the JVM from exiting once the main thread completed.

Comment: @M.J.: The JavaDoc for `Thread.setDaemon()` says: "The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads". So if your thread is a daemon, the JVM will exit. What you need is a non-daemon thread, if you want that to keep the JVM running.

Comment: How about removing the parts of the answer which turned out to be incorrect after the question was clarified?

Answer (score 4):

1) You need `someThread.setDaemon(false)` instead of 'true'. A daemon thread actualy does NOT stop java from shutting down.

From the javadoc:

> void java.lang.Thread.setDaemon(boolean on)
>
> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads.
>
> This method must be called before the thread is started.

2) I think it's not your main, but your run() method that finishes to soon. Try to put a while (true) loop around your doPolling method.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    UnitPoller unitPoller = new UnitPoller();
    while (true)
       unitPoller.doPolling();
}
```

3) It's cleaner to call `join()` inside the main then to rely on daemon thread behavior.

```
    try {
        someThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

4) If you need a clean way to shut down the deamonthread. Consider implementing [InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) to exit the polling task. You can also use the [shutdown hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html).

Answer (score 2):

The term "daemon thread" in Java is a bit misleading, as it really means "that thread is **not** supposed to keep the JVM alive". This means that the JVM will shut down as soon as the last non-daemon thread terminated (as you already stated in your question).

What you are possibly looking for is the [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/) project, which allows to create nice "system services", started through `/etc/init.d/` entries and all. This works on Windows and *nix systems.